# dc tag being incorrectly used

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

There are [lots of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dc) incorrectly using the [dc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dc) tag—they have nothing to do with the reverse polish notation calculator language. Would someone mind retagging them?

Comment: I'm not sure that the calculator needs its own tag, but clearly most of those questions have nothing to do with it.

Comment: If other esoteric languages get their own tag, then dc deserves one too, IMO.

Comment: If questions about Desk Calculator are on topic, then the tag is needed.  How else would you tag this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245664/dc-how-do-i-pop-and-discard-the-top-number-of-the-stack

Comment: Desk Calculator `dc` might be obsolescent these days, but all possible alternate names would be confusing. The same is not true for `domain-controller`, `direct-current` and even for `ldap-dc` or `ldap-domain-component` for which this tag is being actively used.